# How to update rows as per the unique id in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i have below excel and i want to update its rows as per the first row , like 111 is common id for all three first rows now as per the first row i want to update all its rows to same value in below excel first two rows are correct the last one is in correct similar go for 113  using macros ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure I understand what you need, but maybe try something like this:

```
sub ChangeData()
  dim ws as worksheet
  dim i as long

  set ws = activesheet
  
  for i = 3 to ws.range("A3").end(xldown).row
     if ws.range("A" & i - 1).value = ws.range("A" & i).value then
        ws.range("B" & i).value = ws.range("B" & i-1).value
     end if
  next i

end sub
```

Maybe clarify what the ask is if the above doesnt work.